# Asking about the programming industry, and does it fit my personality is acceptable?

Tags: support, specific-question, on-topic-definition

I wrote a quite long, specific question about my experiences about programming, is it acceptable here? I'm searching for the appropriate forum for a long time now. Is there any of them fitting my text linked below?

[link to my question](http://people.inf.elte.hu/dafqaai/question/index.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - career advice is not on-topic here and it will get closed. This kind of question is very unique to you and not generally helpful to the broader community of software developers. I'm not sure how active it is now, but perhaps you could jump into the [Programmers chat room, The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard). It's usually active during the weekdays in the US, but it is a holiday week this week.

Comment: thanks! chat is not a good place to ask such a long question, any other recommendations?

Comment: @FerencDajka Nowhere on the Stack Exchange network, unfortunately. Maybe [one of the places to have more subjective discussions about programming and software development](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6763/where-can-i-have-subjective-discussions-about-programming).

Comment: @FerencDajka you may find the explanations in [Why was my question closed as off topic](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980) to be useful. There are also some subreddits on Reddit that focus on career questions for the computer industry (one of them is linked in that post). The key thing is that many of us feel that career questions take a bit of getting to know *you* and that does take some time. We've had a number of regulars in chat who have gone through career questions changes and we've had hour and longer chats about the various aspects of different sectors of industry

Comment: okay, thanks for the information guys, I really appreciate it